# How to create a method for custom polymer element and call it in a main App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I am writing my custom polymer element. I need to define a method `toggle` for that element. Whenever I create that element in my main HTML, I should be able to call that method. The following code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

loader.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="loader">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog opened id="loadingPage">"{{message}}"</paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            message: "Activating",
            toggle: function() {
                //jQ("#loadingPage").toggle();
                console.log("Internal toggle");
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Index.html

```
<loader id="activationLoading">
        </loader>
<paper-button id="act-submit" raised>
                        Continue
                    </paper-button>
```

index.js

```
jQ('#act-submit').click(function () {
            console.log("toggled");
            jQ('#activationLoading').toggle();
        });
```

P.S. - If I change the method name from `toggle` to `foo`, it throws a javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
button = document.querySelector("#act-submit");
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector("#activationLoading").toggle();
});
```

edit:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="loader-element">
    <template>
        <paper-dialog opened id="loadingPage">"{{message}}"</paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer('loader-element', {
        message: "Activating",
        toggle: function() {
            //jQ("#loadingPage").toggle();
            console.log("Internal toggle");
        }
      });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

after looking back over your element i see that you named it "loader" all polymer elements have to have a - in the name so i renamed "loader-element" second in your script section you didn't call the name of the element you are assigning the script to. if you change that section to match the code below the element should function as expected.

```
      Polymer('loader-element', {
        message: "Activating",
        toggle: function() {
            //jQ("#loadingPage").toggle();
            console.log("Internal toggle");
        }
      });
```

just as a observation i am not sure but i don't think jquery works in polymer elements.

Comment: No. The thing is, I can see "toggled" in my logs i.e. `click` event has been caught up. The problem is with the `toggle` method of `loader`.

Comment: Got it now. As `paper-dialog` gets created as shadow DOM under the shadow root of `core-overlay`, Jquery doesn't work on it.